# date time error while transferring data from csv to mysql

Tags: python

I am very  new to python and trying to get time from csv file which has location id,vrm.,date,time on  it and been inserted into table pay ans display but i need to insert time from csv file  ,  where on table its prints as 00:00:00. how can I get timings from csv instead of entrydatetime

```
tmp = valid_date.split('/')
    iso_date = "%s-%s-%s" % (tmp[2], tmp[1], tmp[0])
    entryDatetime = "%s 00:00:00" % iso_date
    expiryDatetime = "%s 23:59:59" % iso_date
    sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_and_display
        (plate, machine_id, ticket_datetime, expiry_datetime, ticket_name, ticket_price)
        VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (vrm, location_id, entryDatetime, expiryDatetime, "WL", 0)
    print sql_local
    cursor.execute(sql_local)

    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    body = Body()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse the string representing a date and the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in general to parse a csv file.

Edit: you can also use the strptime classmethod of [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects if you're dealing with dates.

Comment: I have time stamp on csv like : 154,NG58YUE,11/03/2014 11:34:51

Comment: I see. datetime objects are probably also a good idea. Anyway, once you've extracted the date using `csv`, you just have to use the right format string. In your case, this is probably `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`